# Routers not getting listed

Tags: openstreetmap, opentripplanner

I started

```
java -Xmx512M -jar /home/ec2-user/OpenTripPlanner/otp-0.20.0-20160422.165451-50-shaded.jar --basePath /home/ec2-user/OpenTripPlanner --server
```

I have this in the base path

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-88 OpenTripPlanner]$ ls -R graphs/
graphs/:
Graph.obj  r1

graphs/1:
Graph.obj  gtfs_8.zip
```

When I hit the URL,
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-88 OpenTripPlanner]$ curl http://localhost:8080/otp/routers
{"routerInfo":[]}

What needs to be done to register the routers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 1.0.0 of OpenTripPlanner, and I had to add a "--autoScan" for OTP to pick up the graphs, (with a "graphs" folder in the "." folder):

```
java -Xmx8G -jar otp-1_0_0.jar --autoReload --autoScan --basePath . --server
```